# Smile vs smile on one's face

Tags: phrase-meaning, expressions

Could you tell me the difference between these three sentences:
(1) I always remembered his smile.
(2) I always remembered his smile on his face.
(3) I always remembered the smile on his face.

Comment: Where did you find these examples? The second one does not seem like something a native speaker would say.

Comment: "The" smile on his face sounds more natural. Using "his" twice seems redundant.

Comment: In the first he's remembering his smile.  In the second he's remembering the smile **on his face**  In other words the first remembers the smile all by itself.  The second remembers the whole face "lit up" by  his smile.

Comment: You gotta admit, two "his" make the sentence a bit clumsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if the speaker is fondly thinking of times past and talking about a person who is no longer with them.

There is no context, so I may be incorrect to assume this, but I think "I will" combined with a present tense "remember" would likely be more natural. If you are writing this sentence, then you are currently remembering. I find that "Remembered" is hard to use naturally outside of "I just remembered" or "I want to be remembered".

### 1: His smile

> I always remembered his smile.
>
> I'll always remember his smile.

This sentence means that when you think of him, you think of those moments when he smiles at you.

### 2: Smile on his face

> I always remembered the smile on his face.
>
> I'll always remember the smile on his face.

This sentence is more about remembering a person as being a happy person who smiles a lot. His face is being characterized as having a smile.